# Is there a build-in function or a simple way to get DDL of a table in PostgreSQL 12?

Tags: postgresql

I want to get DDL of a table in PostgreSQL that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE public.person (
    id serial NOT NULL,
    "name" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    age int4 NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT person_name_uk UNIQUE (name),
    CONSTRAINT person_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

I remember, in MySQL there is a query `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. Is there a similar way to get the same in PostgreSQL?

I am interested in solution for the version PostgreSQL 12.

I need a solution exactly in SQL, so I could use inside of SQL functions. Thus the `pg_dump` of `\d+` don't fit.

Answer (score 1):

Use [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html):

```
pg_dump -U user_name -h host database -s -t table_name -f table_name.sql
```

**FYI**

```
-s or --schema-only : Dump only ddl without data.
-t or --table Dump :  Dump only tables
```

You can try to trace in the `PostgreSQL` log file what `pg_dump` really does.You can use the same strategy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I need a solution exactly in terms of SQL, not with the help of special utilities in terminal. I will edit my question.

Comment: then the dump strategy used by pg_dump could be helpful to identify.

Answer (score 0):

One place to go is the information_schema columns view:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/infoschema-columns.html

You might find this thread relevant:

[How to generate the "create table" sql statement for an existing table in postgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593803/how-to-generate-the-create-table-sql-statement-for-an-existing-table-in-postgr)

A zillion client tools offer to script a `CREATE TABLE` for you. That's another place to find relevant scripts, apart from the excellent suggestion of checking pg_dump itself.