# Autogenerating SQL code for existing constraints

Tags: sql, postgresql

Can I autogenerate SQL code for existing constraint in postgres and get it like the result of other sql query? Pgadmin can do it  [image: (see this picture)], but i need the sql query for constraint by it's name.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks Ulad Kasach for this gem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62548144/13467309

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [the `pg_get_constraintdef` function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html#FUNCTIONS-INFO-CATALOG-TABLE) to construct an SQL statement for the constraint definition.