# In PostgresQL, Is there a sql(not pg_dump) which resemble to "show create table [tablename]" in MySQL?

Tags: postgresql, knex.js, ddl

I want to get "create table clause" by a sql.
Or can I use [Knex.js](http://knexjs.org/) to get "create table clause"?

I've seen this ["How to generate the "create table" sql statement for an existing table in postgreSQL"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593803/how-to-generate-the-create-table-sql-statement-for-an-existing-table-in-postgr)
However, most of the answers uses **pg_dump** which I can't use.
And there're some sql answers, but:

- lack of **specifying schema**
- lack of **indexes** or **primay key**

So, I asked the question again but differently:

- no use of **pg_dump**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some sql like below can be a help:

```
    SELECT                                          
  'CREATE TABLE ' || relname || E'\n(\n' ||
  array_to_string(
    array_agg(
      '    ' || column_name || ' ' ||  type || ' '|| not_null
    )
    , E',\n'
  ) || E'\n);\n'
from
(
  SELECT 
    c.relname, a.attname AS column_name,
    pg_catalog.format_type(a.atttypid, a.atttypmod) as type,
    case 
      when a.attnotnull
    then 'NOT NULL' 
    else 'NULL' 
    END as not_null 
  FROM pg_class c,
   pg_attribute a,
   pg_type t
   WHERE c.relname = 'city'
   AND a.attnum > 0
   AND a.attrelid = c.oid
   AND a.atttypid = t.oid
 ORDER BY a.attnum
) as tabledefinition
group by relname
;
```

Comment: Thank you, really.  But how can I do when I need a specified schema.

Comment: You can refer to the extension of:  https://github.com/lacanoid/pgddl  
If you are free to control your PG database,  you even can install that extension to get the detailed DDL of specified table or other object.